# Is a normal subgroup of G, normal in any subgroups of G containing it?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Its said that if a subgroup K is normal and its quotient group is abelian, then the commutator of G is a subgroup of K. But it's not said that the commutator is normal *in* K. That's why I am wondering...

Comment: If $G' \subseteq K$, then automatically $G' \unlhd K$. For $G' \unlhd G$ and hence $G' \cap H \unlhd H$ for any subgroup $H$ of $G$.

Comment: Theoretically, does my question hold for arbitrary subgroups?

Comment: Yes, in general, if $N \unlhd G$, then $N \cap H \unlhd H$ for any subgroup $H$ of $G$. Try to prove it, it is easy. Your case would be $N \subseteq H$, so $N \cap H=N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need for $hnh^{-1}\in K$ for all $h\in H$ . We know that it is true for all $h\in G$. Does one imply the other?

Comment: Thank you. I thought so, yet was confused by the choice not to be precise and mention the normality.

Comment: It's a valid concern. I asked this qurstion to myself only a couple of weeks ago too :)